# Don't play the socket. You'll get a shocked

Tags: grammar

He took a pen and wanted to play the socket.

> "Don't play the socket. You'll get a shocked."
>
> "Don't play the socket. You'll electric yourself."

How do I say the dangerous of the electric?

Comment: "Don't play **with** the socket."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first sentence needs a preposition.  "Play the socket" would read like the socket is a musical instrument.  You can play the piano, but you play *with* the socket.

And in your options for second sentences:

1. You cannot use an article with "shocked"; if you wanted a noun, it's just "shock".
2. In the second option, "electric" is a noun.  The verbs that would make sense would be "shock" or "electrocute".

Any of the below would be correct:
Don't play with the socket.  You'll get shocked.
Don't play with the socket.  You'll get a shock.
Don't play with the socket.  You'll shock yourself.
Don't play with the socket.  You'll electrocute yourself.

"Electrocute", however, has the connotation of being killed by electricity, not just being injured, so the last sentence describes a more severe danger than the first three.

Comment: Can I say "You'll get an electric shock."?

Comment: Yes, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

My version would be (caution, I'm not a native speaker):

> He took a pen and was going to put it into the socket.
>   "Don't play with the socket! You'll get an electric shock!", I said.